Indian action drama movie about separated twins
This is an Indian action movie about separated twin brothers which I watched around five years ago. This movie was an Indian movie (could be dubbed from other language south Indian language into Telugu) with colors. I could not remember the name of it or the cast of the movie. It was a live action movie. 
Genre : Action, Drama. 
Language :  Telugu but it could be dubbed from other south Indian language (Tamil, Malayalam, Kannada).  
Year : Should be from 2000-2010. I watched it around 5 years ago on  TV but it could be older than that.
Plot details

The movie is about identical twins who were separated by an accident. One of the twins is with biological parents who live in a city but the other one is fostered by a couple who have a good reputation in a village. The twin in the village doesn't know that he is a foster child. He is considered like a leader by some people in the village. He is very good at physical fights. The twin in the city is a wise and educated unlike his brother.
The one who is with the parents finds out that there is a twin brother to him and goes to the village to bring him back to parents but receives a protest from the family there.  He somehow meets his twin, talks to him and reveals the flashback. After a talk, they agree to switch places.  
The village twin goes to his biological parents and lives there. The wise and urban twin stays in the village tries to solve the problems of his twin's rivals using his intellect. He gets succeeded in it.

In the end the original identities of both are revealed and both the families end up happy because the village twin chooses to live with the adopted family and still loves his original parents. 

Seems to be Vel (2007). This movie is dubbed and released as Deva in Telugu.
Plot:
Twins Vel and Vasu are separated and grow up in different families. Later Vasu finds to Vel's family and wants get him back to their biological parents. Vel is surprised about his true story but refuses to got with Vasu because he (Vel) has to protect his family. 
After that there was a bad guy, some action, explosions and in the end the twin's biological mother allows Vel to stay in the family who raised him 
Relevant article on Wikipedia. From that article,

Upon release, the film was dubbed and released in Telugu as Deva and in Hindi as Main Faisla Karunga.


